# Windows 10 ethernet not working, nor network reset, but works fine in linux

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, dhcp

I temporarily live in flat where there is only a wired connection. In Linux it works fine (therefore I know problem is not in hardware nor in cable), but in Windows 10 I cannot connect. I tried many things but nothing works:

- [network reset](https://www.howtogeek.com/265870/how-to-reset-your-entire-network-in-windows-10-and-start-from-scratch/) does nothing. After reset and system restart I don't get any message asking to "allow your PC to be discoverable" or any indication that network was really reset
- Troubleshoot windows tool only says I don't have valid IP configuration", which is clear, since it cannot connect to obtain IP address by DHCP
- I tried to enable/disable adapter, or uninstall/reinstall driver ... no effect
- I also tried to enable some runtime services connected to "network discovery" as recommended here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMr5Xd9dyIQ or here https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49652-turn-off-network-discovery-windows-10-a.html . This is because my landlord said: *You should check your Microsoft settings, that it allows/activates network search automatically; you should activate DHCP.* ... but I guess until I obtain an IP address from DHCP this has no effect.

There are two screenshots
[1)Ethernet_Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVbrg.jpg)
[2)Troubleshooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2ZA1.jpg)

My hardware is "Realtek PCIe GbE family controller" in Lenovo Ideapad Y700 (15") laptop

---

EDIT: result after trying El8tedN8te's advice to set IPs according to Linux:

From Linux:

```
enp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  
          inet addr:10.102.255.149  Bcast:10.102.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::975a:f98d:7b6f:539b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3581010 (3.5 MB)  TX bytes:986192 (986.1 KB)

prokop@prokop-Lenovo-ideapad-Y700-15ISK:~$ nmcli dev show enp9s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp9s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.102.255.149/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.102.255.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 134.76.10.46/32, nh = 10.102.255.254, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             134.76.10.46
IP4.DNS[2]:                             134.76.33.21
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          ibz.gwdg.de
IP4.WINS[1]:                            134.76.26.21
IP4.WINS[2]:                            134.76.11.71
IP4.WINS[3]:                            134.76.26.26
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::4860:b051:6a87:3e6f/64
```

ipconfig with manual IP and DNS:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::848:5ab1:b52d:49b5%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.102.255.149
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.102.255.254
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ7iA.jpg) after IP and DNS set manually

ipconfig after switching back to DHCP:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::848:5ab1:b52d:49b5%6
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.73.181
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

EDIT 2:

```
C:\Users\Prokop Hapala>ipconfig /release
Windows IP Configuration
No operation can be performed on Wi-Fi while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 11 while it has its media disconnected.
An error occurred while releasing interface Ethernet : An address has not yet been associated with the network endpoint.

C:\Users\Prokop Hapala>ipconfig /renew
Windows IP Configuration
No operation can be performed on Wi-Fi while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 11 while it has its media disconnected.
__ wait inifinite time __
```

EDIT 3

```
C:\Users\Prokop Hapala>ipconfig  /all
Windows IP Configuration
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : LAPTOP-OH29KS41
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A4-34-D9-50-AB-E5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A4-34-D9-50-AB-E6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 50-7B-9D-A1-1B-FB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e192:18a2:5a6a:5456%2(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.84.86(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 105937821
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-43-75-55-50-7B-9D-A1-1B-FB
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

C:\Users\Prokop Hapala>arp -a
Interface: 169.254.84.86 --- 0x2
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  169.254.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Comment: It seems there is a rogue DHCP server assigning bad address assignments on your network (1. You are receiving an incorrect subnet 2. The address is strange). Set to DHCP and try `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` if that doesn't work either please edit what the IP address of the attempted DHCP server is (should be listed under `ipconfig /all`) and also the mac address `arp -a` where it is next to dynamic with that same IP address.

Comment: I tried this `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` (see EDIT 2). My impression is it does not communicate with network servers at all. Maybe the land adapter does not work in windows (although I tired to update drivers)

Comment: How about `ipconfig /all` and `arp -a`?

Comment: I was a bit uncertain what to do with it ... but If you just want to see output, I attached it under `EDIT 3`

Comment: Disable IPv6 protocol by unchecking it in the ethernet adapter properties. An IPV6 DHCP is assigning you an IPV4 and IPV6 address. Disable it and your problem will likely be solved (I hope)

Comment: I tried to disable(uncheck) it and not change. I also still have the same IP address.

Comment: I tried to disable(uncheck) IPv6, but no change. I also still have the same IP address

Comment: A bit late... have you tried rebooting the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ifconfig` in a Linux terminal (since you already have this) and write down these addresses from the output of the command:

- Default Gateway
- Subnet Mask - though possibly unneeded
- Every DNS listed
- Current IPv4 Address of your machine - though possibly unneeded

Then in Windows, in Ethernet Properties, select IPv4/TCP properties, and set everything to be obtained automatically (though we will set some addresses).

Select the "Advanced..." button and inside the IP Settings tab, select "Add..." underneath "Default Gateways", and enter the Default Gateway address that you obtained from Linux accordingly and keep checked "Automatic Metric"

Inside the DNS tab, select "Add..." underneath "DNS Server Addresses..." and type in accordingly in this order:

1. The Default Gateway (*usually* the default gateway also acts as a DNS)
2. Each DNS list in the order that they were displayed from the `ifconfig` command in Linux, except the Default Gateway address that had already been entered (if list). If it is not listed, for troubleshooting later you can remove it, as it may not work.

Press Ok, and try out the new settings.

If this does not work disable DHCP by clicking the bullet button "Use the following IP address", and then inside the "Advanced TCP/IP Settings" dialog within the IP Settings tab, click "Add..." and enter the machine IP Address and the Subnet Mask that was used under Linux.

Press Ok, and try out the new settings.

Comment: thank you, I tried that, but no change. I still does "identifying" for few minutes, and than resolve to "unidentified network", and I reciive zero packet

Comment: Would you please give the results of `ipconfig` after resetting to completely DHCP once again?

Comment: ok, I attached that to my original message. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @ProkopHapala, did you try without the WINS addresses?

Comment: now I tried without WINS, no change

Comment: anyway, I will accept you answer just to thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing that you didn't mention the firewall at all. It's worth checking, since if it has a restrictive ruleset (I don't know the default behavior of Windows Firewall), it will block the DHCP traffic.

Comment: If this is the issue, the OP should examine and take the approach found in this answer https://superuser.com/a/564711/543035

Comment: Hi I tied to disable the firewall or non-private networks ... but no effect. (switch "block incomming connection" was off)