# Set Windows Firwall to block all outbound but allow DHCP and web use

Tags: dhcp, windows-firewall, netsh

I am trying to set Windows firewall to block default public profile, but am having difficulty when outbound activity is set to block by default, despite including allow rules for DHCP and DNS.

Failure typically results in connection to wireless services without internet access. In other words, router association and DHCP may take place but do not provide full wireless functionality and access to web.

Worse, when enacted, failure frequently results in the inoperability of wireless adapter altogether, even when a working firewall policy is reinstated, requiring adapter to be disabled and reenabled and computer restarted to restore normal wireless functionality. I understand in Windows netsh is used to configure both firewall and TCP/IP stack and adapter state, which is not the case in other operating systems with which I have had experience.

Before connection action, the complete network will remain visible in Windows GUI. Following failure, the network and wifi icon will disappear, and the airplane mode icon will remain disactivated and unusable.

These results occur when firewall is set to block by default in either the advanced firewall GUI or in .bat script, which I include here.

These results were checked against two public wireless locations, to ensure absence of specific wireless service failure.

Note that to further avoid some simple failure, DHCP port allowances were opened up to 67-68 in all cases to test and both UDP and TCP rules for DNS were included.

Logging shows an inexplicable drop action for DHCP and DNS.

Note that evaluation order from default block to specific allow rules was not assumed to be a problem, and I would be surprised if this is the case. Here a default is specified for all packets to which I assume explicit allow rules the exception outbound, but there is some confusion as to whether this should be the case.
See the following two answers on Superuser for examples of statement. The second example is very similar to my own policy tests, which utterly destroy wireless functionality but are claimed to work.

[Configure Windows Firewall to allow DHCP client and specific remote IPs only](https://superuser.com/questions/564701/configure-windows-firewall-to-allow-dhcp-client-and-specific-remote-ips-only)

[How to block everything (all incoming and outgoing internet access) except those applications are in firewall white-list?](https://superuser.com/questions/1182658/how-to-block-everything-all-incoming-and-outgoing-internet-access-except-those)

Bat script rules and log excerpt are shown below.

```
REM Set policy for all profiles: 
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles firewallpolicy blockinbound,blockoutbound
    
REM Core networking in: 
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule NAME="CoreNetworking_DHCP-UDP" dir=in interfacetype=wireless ACTION=ALLOW protocol=UDP remoteip=dhcp localport=68 remoteport=67 program="%WINDIR%\System32\svchost.exe" service=dhcp ENABLE=YES
    
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule NAME="CoreNetworking_DNSCache-UDP" dir=in interfacetype=wireless ACTION=ALLOW protocol=UDP remoteip=dns remoteport=53 program="%WINDIR%\System32\svchost.exe" service=dnsclient ENABLE=YES
    
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule NAME="CoreNetworking_DNSCache-TCP" dir=in interfacetype=wireless ACTION=ALLOW protocol=TCP remoteip=dns remoteport=53 program="%WINDIR%\System32\svchost.exe" service=dnsclient ENABLE=YES
    
REM Core networking out: 
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule NAME="CoreNetworking_DHCP-UDP" dir=out interfacetype=wireless ACTION=ALLOW protocol=UDP remoteip=dhcp localport=67 remoteport=68 program="%WINDIR%\System32\svchost.exe" service=dhcp ENABLE=YES
    
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule NAME="CoreNetworking_DNSCache-UDP" dir=out interfacetype=wireless ACTION=ALLOW protocol=UDP remoteip=dns remoteport=53 program="%WINDIR%\System32\svchost.exe" service=dnsclient ENABLE=YES
    
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule NAME="CoreNetworking_DNSCache-TCP" dir=out interfacetype=wireless ACTION=ALLOW protocol=TCP remoteip=dns remoteport=53 program="%WINDIR%\System32\svchost.exe" service=dnsclient ENABLE=YES
```

```
2023-04-21 17:59:11 DROP UDP 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 68 67 0 - - - - - - - SEND
2023-04-21 17:59:11 DROP UDP [redacted] 8.8.8.8 49915 53 0 - - - - - - - SEND

2023-04-21 17:43:50 DROP UDP 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 68 67 0 - - - - - - - SEND
2023-04-21 17:43:50 DROP UDP [redacted] 8.8.8.8 64584 53 0 - - - - - - - SEND
```