# Windows 8.1: Force all traffic through VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, gateway, windows-8

I have applications running which need to access a URL through the VPN - NOT through the general internet.

I want to be able to specify that all traffic MUST flow through the VPN, but I don't know how to configure this in Windows 8.

Note: I am using a Checkpoint VPN client which does not seem to display as a Virtual Network Adapter in Windows Network Connections (as it used to in XP).

I've tried "route add [desiredip] [vpnip]" but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate: http://superuser.com/a/456326/167187

Comment: @Vinayak, thanks for that link, but those instructions assume that the VPN is visible as a network adaptor within the Network Connections GUI. In my case, using the Checkpoint VPN application, it is not.

Ideally, I can do the same, but through the commmand line?

Comment: Are you saying you can't see [something like this](http://www.purevpn.com/upload/cms/tutorial/pic/firewall-step17.jpg) in Network and Sharing Center after you connect to the VPN?

Comment: I'm very intrigued as to why the route didn't work as that sounds correct to me. If you add the route and run a tracert to the IP what route do you get?

Comment: @Vinayak - yes, that is correct. I am using the http://www.checkpoint.com client (E80.42) which does not display as a virtual adaptor like your screenshot.

Comment: @CharlesH I will try a tracert and get back to you.

Comment: @CraigJohnstone I have never used Check Point VPN, so I downloaded the E80.42 client from [here](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=30348) and while installing it, I saw [this](http://imgur.com/TV39SYI.png). I also noticed that it installs a network driver and that the virtual network adapter is [shown in Device Manager](http://imgur.com/n2BTuw4.png) (with "show hidden devices" enabled)

Comment: so I think you may have configured your VPN incorrectly. [Have you checked your public IP address](http://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip&hl=en) before and after connecting to the VPN?. If you have set it up correctly, you should have a different IP after you've connected to the VPN.

Comment: Once you have your VPN working correctly, the easy way to get Windows to use the VPN network as the default is to assign a low connection metric to the VPN's virtual network adapter (e.g. 1). Make sure the connection metric for your regular network adapter (i.e. your Ethernet or Wi-Fi connection you use to access the Internet) is set to a value higher than that of the VPN's network adapter (e.g. 10). You'll have to disable "automatic metric" to set the metric values manually. More info on that [here](http://goo.gl/n1fiQv) and [here](http://goo.gl/OgiQU5)