# How to use iptables to allow traffic only through ONE SPECIFIC VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to allow all traffic from my Banana PI running Lubuntu to only go to my LAN or otherwise through an VPN Server. I'm following this guide: http://joelslowik.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/setup-iptables-for-vpn-and-local.html

Essentially it says I should use these rules:

```
#Allow loopback device (internal communication)
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
#Allow all local traffic.
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
#Allow VPN establishment
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
#Accept all TUN connections (tun = VPN tunnel)
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
#Set default policies to drop all communication unless specifically allowed
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

But as far as I understand it, that will allow traffic through ANY VPN (or anything with a network interface starting with "tun" for that matter).

I tried to use

```
iptables -A INPUT -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
```

with the IP Address of the VPN Server, but that doesn't seem to work either, it simply won't connect to the VPN.

So how should I do this? I did the exact same thing on Windows using the Windows Firewall (following [this](https://superuser.com/a/456326/399511) guide), just blocking any IP Address except the local ones and the one of the VPN Server and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears like you are using OpenVPN, one thing you could easily do is to give your VPN tun device an explicit name instead of using tunN.

It is perfectly valid to put something like. `dev tun_home` in your OpenVPN configuration.  This will result in the tunnel device being named `tun_home`.  You can then use this in your firewall rules instead of using a wildcard device name match `tun+`.

Comment: Well I guess this would work... I just still don't feel comfortable making it dependent on the name of the network interface which, as far as I understand, any program can create one of any name. Do you know, why the IP-based rules don't work (considering it works perfectly on Windows)?

Comment: No ideal, you probably have written your rules, wrong, but it is difficult to tell since you haven't given us the full set of rules you used when it failed.  You also haven't shared the routing tables, so it isn't clear to me what will be crossing the tun interface.

Comment: Conversely, the tunx device should not be changing.  Find out what the name is on your installation (tun0 perhaps) and change `tun+` to `tun0`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose here that you want all non local traffic to go through the VPN (internet access for example). If this is true, I think it would be easier and better to use the routing table to do what you want instead of the firewall. You could define your default route to use the VPN instead of the current default.

```
route add default dev tun0
```

or something similar and remove the current default route.

On the other hand, if what you want is really to block anything that is not local or coming from the VPN then you are in the right direction using iptables.